# put formula in vba based on cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to put a dynamic formula as follows via vba program:

```
=IFERROR(B9,0)+IFERROR(C9,0)+IFERROR(D9,0)+IFERROR(E9,0)++IFERROR(F9,0)+IFERROR(G9,0)+IFERROR(H9,0)+IFERROR(I9,0)+IFERROR(J9,0)+IFERROR(K9,0)+IFERROR(R9,0)+IFERROR(S9,0)+IFERROR(#REF!,0)+IFERROR(#REF!,0)+IFERROR(#REF!,0)+IFERROR(#REF!,0)+IFERROR(#REF!,0)
```

I have a cell which stores the number of cols required in the Formula (F3).
Now if the value in F3 is 18, what i wish to accomplish is the formula to be in the above format from cell B9 to cell S9 (which is the 19 col, since i start from B to F3+1). Easier to use Sum but that wont serve my purpose. Because if any of the cells in the range in N/A (very much possible), the sum should not be N/A but the sum of rest of the values.

Comment: i want all cells to add up. If any cell has an error, it should be replaced by 0.

Comment: doesnt work. Although i am wondering why. Seeing everything online for aggregate still not working. I am puzzled.
=aggregate(9,6,B9:S9) returns #NAME?

Comment: Please type this formula in cell apart from range by typing ` =SUM(IF(ISERROR(B9:S9),"",B9:S9))` , Then enter the formula by pressing ` control+shift+enter` keys simultaneously. You should get the correct result. This is to be entered as an array formula. If you have correctly entered formula you will see `{    }` curly braces around the formula. It should work if entered correctly. This sum can be performed in a loop also. If interested I will mention that too.

Comment: I am getting correct results for both this formula as well as loop formula on a sample data. It checks correctly all general type of errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try This. It will sum and also replace error cell with `0`. It is a very simple loop hence not commented.

```
Sub SumNumwithoutError()
  Dim rn As Range
  Dim wrn As Range
  Dim xSum As Long
  On Error Resume Next
  xSum = 0
  Set wrn = Application.Selection
  Set wrn = Application.InputBox("Range", wrn.Address, Type:=8)
  For Each rn In wrn
   If (IsError(rn.Value)) Then
        rn.Value = 0
   End If
   If Not (IsError(rn.Value)) Then
       xSum = xSum + rn.Value
   End If
  Next
  MsgBox xSum
End Sub
```